# Troubles with ng-translate in multi-modules angular app

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ngx-translate

I have an Angular App consisting of several modules:
1. app
2. display
3. profile
4. Shared

The translation-service is registered in the shared module. This works for the modules (app, display).

In the Display Module there is a component which is responsible for showing an object. This is exported.

If the component is displayed in the context of App, the translations and all other imports works.
If I integrate this component in the Lady Loading Module (Profile), all dependencies and the translation are missing.

What am I doing wrong?
Where can I read about it?

Thanks for the hints.

Comment: In shared module: `imports: [TranslateModule], exports: [TranslateModule]`. In app module: `imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot({ loader: {...}})]`. How to set a loader object you can see on tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. One loader setup for lazy loading modules:**

**shared.module.ts**

```js
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

// Inside @NgModule
imports: [TranslateModule],
exports: [TranslateModule],
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
// No need to set up isolate !!! defoult is false it meens loader will work on all lazy loaded modules
imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot({loader: {...}, isolate: false})]
```

**2. For big application lazy loaded translations:**

**JSON files**

- assets/i18n/app/en.json and fr.json and how many languages you want.
- assets/i18n/home/en.json and fr.json and how many languages you want.

> For root or app.module.ts see above: **app.module.ts** and change isolate to true and loader path to: assets/i18n/app/*.json.

**Lazy loaded home.module.ts loadder set to path: assets/i18n/home/*.json.**

```js
imports: [TranslateModule.forChild({loader: {...}, isolate: true})]
```

Now root and children will have their own lazy loaded translations.